# Model undefined when passing Model from View to Controller using AJAX

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

When I tried to used debugger; in ajax to check if I'm able to serialize the form it say it is "undefined". I don't encounter an error but The value i input in the view does not pass to the controller. This is my reference https://stick2basic.wordpress.com/2013/04/14/how-to-pass-model-from-view-to-controller-using-jquery/

**VIEW**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnsubmit').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if ($("#OrderForm").valid()) { //if you use validation
                $.ajax({
                    url: $("#OrderForm").attr('action'),
                    type: $("#OrderForm").attr('method'),
                    data: $("#OrderForm").serialize(),
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("success");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("_Order", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id =  "OrderForm" }))
{
<div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MerchantEmail, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MerchantEmail, new { @Value = "abc@gmail.com",@class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MerchantEmail, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

<div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="button" value="Create" id="btnsubmit" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
}
```

**Controller**

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult _Order(OrderModel model)
        {
List<OrderModel> orderlist = new List<OrderModel>();
            if (Session["OrderList"] != null)
            {
                orderlist = Session["OrderList"] as List<OrderModel>;
                orderlist.Add(model);
            }
            Session["OrderList"] = orderlist;
            return PartialView();
}
```

**MODEL**

```
public class OrderModel
    {
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [StringLength(35)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [StringLength(35)]
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        [StringLength(35)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Address { get; set; }
        [StringLength(40)]
        public string Province { get; set; }
        [StringLength(40)]
        public string Town { get; set; }
        [StringLength(13)]
        public string MobileNo { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please fill up Merchant Email.")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string MerchantEmail { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the exact amount.")]
        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        public float OrderAmount { get; set; }

        public string OrderSkuCode { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please fill up order details.")]
        [StringLength(5000)]
        public string OrderDetails { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: The code you have shown will work fine. Are you saying that `$("#OrderForm").serialize()` returns `undefined`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes, When i add break point to _Order httppost the OrderModel is Empty.

Comment: Show the model for `OrderModel`

Comment: @StephenMuecke check the edited version

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you have shown. If you do `var data = $('#OrderForm').serialize();` it will return `{ MerchantEmail: 'someValue' }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke it says undefined in alert message

Comment: Then its due to other code you have not shown us.

Comment: @StephenMuecke It's a partial view there is no other complicated code

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you are doing at the same time, you can have ajax or post the data directly to the controller.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("_Order", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id =  "OrderForm" }))
{
<div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MerchantEmail, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MerchantEmail, new { @Value = "abc@gmail.com",@class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MerchantEmail, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

<div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="button" value="Create" id="btnsubmit" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
}
```

Here you are posting the data directly to the controller (Ajax is for Asynchronous Transfer) , this will by pass the Ajax request in the script.

If you want to post it through Ajax here is the code changes you need to do

```
<form id="form1">
<div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MerchantEmail, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MerchantEmail, new { @Value = "abc@gmail.com",@class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MerchantEmail, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

<div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="button" value="Create" id="btnsubmit" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
 </form>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnsubmit').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var data = new FormData($("#form1")[0]);
            if ($("#OrderForm").valid()) { //if you use validation
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("_Order","Your Controller Name")',
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: data,
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("success");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```